# Initialize Socket.IO from server instance in another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to initialize my socket inside a route and according to [documents](http://socket.io/docs/) I have to pass server instance to my socket. I have a separate server.js file like this:

```js
var app = require('./app');
var http = require('http');

var port = '2002';
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function(err){
 if(err)
  console.log(err);
 else
  console.log('Server listening on port : ' + port);
 });

module.exports = server;
```

and my router:

```js
var express = require('express');
var server = require('../server');
var router = express.Router();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
 res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.emit('server emit', { hello: 'server emit' });
   socket.on('client emit', function (data) {
  console.log("Server received : " + data);
  });
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my client script:

```js
   var socket = io('http://localhost:2002');
   socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.on('server emit', function(data) {
     console.log('inside eventtt');
     console.log(data);
     
   });
  });
```

But I face this error in my browser console:

```
socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET http://localhost:2002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LPajDxI
```

I think the problem is due to wrong initialization of my socket on the server side, but I don't know how to handle the problem.